# Where the result of query is displayed in hyperledger composer?

Tags: javascript, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

In hyperledger composer where the result of query is displayed? And why we need a separate file when we can query in js file.

Answer (score 0):

Composer configures the named queries for a business network in a source file called `queries.qry`

See more here -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/business-network/query.html

The results can be seen by running `composer-rest-server` after you've deployed a network with defined queries - these queries are exposed as REST API endpoints.

Check out the tutorial for an example of defining, then testing queries to see results -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/queries.html

Specifically the section 'Test the Trading REST APIs and create some data'